# Serverless Error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [<function name>LogGroup] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I was trying to use the serverless monitoring tools and ran sls to connect it to my serverless account. After that whenever I try to deploy, I get this message

Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [CsGetIndexLogGroup] in the Resources block of the template.

My sls template does not have a Resources block. I tried to add an empty Resources block but that did nothing.

```
provider:
  versionFunctions: false
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  api_endpoint: ${file(./config/${self:provider.stage}.env.json):api_endpoint}
plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-nested-stack
functions:  
  csGetIndex:
    handler: handler.getCurrentIndex
    description: Get everything that is indexed
    events:
      - http:
          path: csgetindex
          method: get
          cors: true
```

not showing other functions or the post will get too long.